# Using blob file download says File is corrupted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob

I am trying to download the file in angular js. For that, I have used the blob concept . File is getting download successfully but when I open that file it says File is corrupted.

```
var saveData = (function () {
  var a = document.createElement("button");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  return function (excelData, fileName) {
    //    var blob = b64toBlob(excelData, contentType);
    blob = new Blob([excelData], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"}),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };                   
}());
```

Comment: This is probably not your issue, but`a` should be an anchor `<a>` element, not a `<button>` which doesn't have neither `href` nor `download` attributes.
For your issue, the problem probably comes from before this part, when `excelData` is generated. What does this variable holds ?

Comment: `excelData` is the data that I wanted to see in excel file.

Comment: in which format is it ? `plain/text` ? *(bad)*, `arrayBuffer` ? *(better)¨*, something else ? *(probably bad)*. What do you see in the console when you do `console.log(excelData)`?

Comment: Data is there in excel format...`{type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"}`

Comment: No... this is not the data, this is just the MIMEType, which is actually quite useless when you don't send the blob to a server ; except for `text/...`, where you can add an encoding rule, since once downloaded, this MIMEType will have disappeared and will be only guessed through either the file extension (bad, but browsers do this...), or the file's magic numbers (which are `504b0304` for xlsx files.) So if the first 4 bytes of `excelData` read as hex are not `50 4B 03 04` excelData is not an xlsx data.